# How to create a post-site maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I used to development several Maven custom plugins (compile, report, etc). I don't find how to create a post-site maven plugin

I succeeded in creating a Maven Site goal like for example :

```
/**
 * Generation of part 1 of qualitychecker report in the site phase
 *
 * @goal qcrgoalreporting01
 * 
 * @phase site
 */
public class QcrReporting01Mojo
    extends AbstractMavenReport {
...
}
```

I have tried by setting @phase pre-site, but fails (the goal is ignored)

Could you provide a link or an example for a post-site phase ?
Thanks

Comment: I have never seen this notation for plugin definitions, where does it come from? I use the Mojo annotation `@Mojo(name = "scan", requiresProject = true, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST, defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VERIFY)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JF Meier, I'll write my answer as a reminder.

I used to write old "Javadocs Tags" since maven 2 (approx 10 years ago), it is equivalent to "Java annotations", see [MavenDocs](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html).

My issue was in fact that the "site" global phase executes only the pre-site then site phases, but not the post-phase.

I changed "mvn site" to "mvn post-site". It executes pre-site, then site, then post-site phases.